# How to control xml-serialization style of empty collections in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

How can I control xml-serialization style of empty collections in C#?

For example, I need an empty collection to be serialized into pair of open-closing tags:

```
<SomeEmptyCollection>
</SomeEmptyCollection>
```

instead of just one tag

```
<SomeEmptyCollection />
```

Comment: Have you tried searching it? Quick google search gives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539555/prevent-self-closing-tags-in-xmlserializer-when-no-data-is-present http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932093/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-self-closing-tags-when-using-xml-serialization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802813/xml-serialization-in-c-sharp

Comment: Or just google ".net xml serialization self closing tags"

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for an answer and have already read all information by links you provided, but they don't contain an answer. I just understand that I should create my own XmlWriter, but I already knew that :) So my question is: are there some existing implementations of such behaviour?